# list.index() not quite working

Tags: python

I'm using this piece of code for a small program I need to design for a friend. The problem is can't quite get it to work.

I am designing a program that uses list for vegetables and fruits. 
For example my list is:

```
smallist = [["apple", 2], ["banana", 3], ["strawberry",1]]
item = input("Please give the name of the fruit\n\n")

smallist.index(item)
print (smallist)
```

The problem is when I then try to find the index of lets say the apple. I just say that the apple does not exist.

```
smallist.index(item)
ValueError: 'apple' is not in list
```

I can't figure out why it won't show me the apple with its value which in this case would be 2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`apple` is not *in* `smallist`. It is in a *nested* list contained inside of `smallist`.

You'll have to search for it with a loop:

```
for i, nested in enumerate(smallist):
    if item in nested:
        print(i)
        break
```

Here `enumerate()` creates a running index for us while looping over `smallist` so we can print the index where it was found.

If what you wanted to do was print the other value we don't need the index:

```
for name, count in smallist:
    if name == item:
        print(count)
        break
```

But it'd be easier to use a dictionary here:

```
small_dict = dict(smallist)
print(small_dict.get(item, 'Not found'))
```

Comment: In my case i only needed the index value so i can then use a list.pop to remove the item edit the value that it has and then append it back again. I will check the piece of code that u just suppplied. EDIT: Sorry for any confusion. I want it so that the people who type into this program just type the name of the fruit or vegetable and then my program finds this word and its corresponding value.

Answer (score 0):

"apple" isn't in `smallist`, ["apple", 2] is.

Your data would fit much better into a dictionary:

```
smaldict = {'apple': 2, 'banana': 3, 'strawberry': 1}

item = input("Please give the name of the fruit\n\n")
if item in smaldict:
    print(smaldict[item])
else:
    print('"{item}" is not in the dictionary.'.format(item=item))
```